# How can I execute cinelerra-cv?

Tags: cinelerra

I installed Cinelerra and I can't find it in my computer
Here's my message.

```
smallhuman@smallhuman-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cinelerra-cv is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  efibootmgr secureboot-db shim
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

It looks cinelerra-cv has installed in my computer, but I can't find it.
I hit super key, type 'cinelerra' or 'cinelerra-cv', but nothing founded.
And If I try to search Cinerra-cv in Software Center, there is no program like it.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it from terminal.Run the below command on terminal,

```
cinelerra
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it can take quite some time before an application shows up in the dashboard/launcher menu. Fire up a terminal and write:

```
which cinelerra
```

or

```
which cinelerra-cv
```

to get the path to your program. Now you can run it via that path or create a launcher shortcut pointing to this path.

Answer (score 0):

there is also another command to find cinelerra on your Ubuntu: `

> $ whereis cinelerra

`. Which in my case returns

> cinelerra:

As I looked on the net, there is no quality explanation for starting cinelerra

UPDATE: I found the answer here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102351
It goes like this: first you update your Ubuntu Software Center 's sources in which you put cinellera by typing in terminal

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

Then you have cinelerra in Ubuntu Software Center, and just install one by one the components needed. You have x86 and x64 versions.

After this, you have it in your software list (Dash Home), so just click on it and start it. Hope this helps